# how to display 2D array in C# windows form?

Tags: c#

I don't know how to display it on a listboxt when I try to put code to display it error always occurs

```
int arrayRows = 5;
int arrayCols = 3;

int[,] arrayTimes;
arrayTimes = new int[arrayRows , arrayCols];
int mult = 0;

for (int i = 0; i != arrayRows; i++)
{
    mult = mult + 10;
    for (int j = 0; j != arrayCols; j++)
    {
        arrayTimes[i, j] = mult;
        mult = mult * 10;
    }

    mult = mult / 1000;
    listBox1.Items.Add("arrayPos= " + i + "values =" + arrayTimes[i,j]);            
}
```

Comment: What error occur?

Comment: This code won't even compile. You're trying to use j outside it's scope.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i != arrayRows; i++)` Never use that ending condition. Rather use `i < arrayRows` what if, for some reasons, `i` become greater than `arrayRows` ?

Comment: the output should be like this 
arrayPos= 0,0 val=10
arrayPos= 0,1 val=100
arrayPos= 0,2 val=1000
arrayPos= 1,0 val =20
arrayPos= 1,1 val =200
arrayPos= 1,2 val =2000
arrayPos= 2,0 val =30
arrayPos= 2,1 val =300
arrayPos= 2,2 val =3000
arrayPos= 3,0 val =40
arrayPos= 3,1 val =400
arrayPos= 3,2 val =4000
arrayPos= 4,0 val = 50
arrayPos= 4,1 val =500
arrayPos= 4,2 val =5000

Comment: But what error you are getting?

Comment: @Dnomyar96 is right, j is declared in the `for` loop and exists only inside its scope (`{ }`)

Comment: https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s7p4.html in this show the output  of the code but i dunno what code i will use in the listbox :(

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this :

```
int arrayRows = 5;
int arrayCols = 3;

int[,] arrayTimes;
arrayTimes = new int[arrayRows , arrayCols];
int mult = 0;

for (int i = 0; i != arrayRows; i++)
{
    mult = mult + 10;
    for (int j = 0; j != arrayCols; j++)
    {
        arrayTimes[i, j] = mult;

        listBox1.Items.Add("arrayPos= " + i + "values =" + arrayTimes [i,j]);

        mult = mult * 10;
    }
    mult = mult / 1000;
}
```

You are using `j` after you get out of the `for (int j = 0; j != arrayCols; j++){ ... }` structure.

Comment: please help me i am new to C# programming